# Mockito 1.9.5 + Dexmaker on Android in Eclipse get NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I need to test one application on Android in Eclipse. I made Android Test Project and in it this class. I need some mock so i use Mockito so i added into my test project library this: mockito-all-1.9.5.jar, dexmaker-1.0.jar, dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar

```
package metrocar.view.test;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class OBD2Test extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    public void testInStock() {
        Handler mHandler = mock(Handler.class);
    }
}
```

But when i try to run it against real device i get this error. How can i fix it?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.Mockito
at metrocar.view.test.OBD2Test.testInStock(OBD2Test.java:12)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

Comment: Ansver is to create libs directory in root of project and put all jar inside.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the unit test, the JARs that you depend on (mockito) need to be exported to the device that the test runs on. You can have mockito on your classpath in Eclipse, so your test compiles, but that´s not enough. Mockito seems to need to be specifically in the libs directory under your Android Test Project, and it should appear in your Android depedencies.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. I tried that and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

For documentation purposes, if you are using KitKat and ibarbarisi's answer is not working, undo every thing and make sure your using Dalvik not ART. It's seems you cannot run instrumentation with ART.

Checkout this question for more details: [INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError running Android Instrumentation tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514588/instrumentation-result-shortmsg-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-running-android)